# Is 'natural beauties' a common phrase to describe places of outstanding beauty?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

When I look the word 'beauty' up in monolingual dictionaries I see it's mostly used as 'uncountable.' The only example I could find was in Collins Dictionary.

> The beauties of something are its attractive qualities or features.
> [literary]
> *He was beginning to enjoy the beauties of nature.*

I'm wondering if we can we use it 'natural beauties' as in the following sentence:

> I'm interested in natural beauties, so I prefer going to the lake to relax and refresh.

Comment: Beauties are not places. I'm interested in nature's beauty or the beauty of nature. beauty is a mass noun, like poverty and wealth. You might say that the vines in your vineyards are real beauties, though.

Comment: *I'm interested in **the beauty of nature*** (or ***Nature's wonders***, personifying "Mother Nature").

Comment: @FumbleFingers I said beauty of nature.

Comment: Britain has designated [AONBs](https://landscapesforlife.org.uk/) - Areas of Outstanding Natural Beauty. Perhaps I'm showing my age here, but _beauties_ in the plural seems to me to carry a suggestion that you are seeking attractive women.

Comment: Sure, the natural beauty of national parks [US], too. Also, a woman can be said to be a natural beauty (no make-up needed).

Comment: In Britain, maybe elsewhere, a place can be a [beauty spot](https://www.visitbritain.com/gb/en/uk-beauty-spots-bucket-list), somwhere with beautiful landscape, scenery, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Beauty is normally a "quality".  It is a *abstract* property that something might have. Such abstract nouns are uncountable.

However, it can be used to mean "a beautiful thing" in some situations:

Talking about a very attractive woman "Naomi Campbell is a famous beauty". Unfortunately this sense is suggested by "I like natural beauties".

In informal language, it can be used to mean an excellent example of something: "That yacht's a real beauty. What is she, a 24 footer?".  "What a goal, a real left-foot beauty!"

It isn't used to mean "a beautiful natural place"  So your example isn't idiomatic. But you can use "beauty" in its uncountable form

> I'm interested in natural beauty, so I prefer going to the lake to relax and refresh.